# NSArray Vs. NSMutableArray Issues

Tags: ios, nsmutablearray, nsarray

In my app, I setup an `NSArray` and add all objects with an extension of HTML from the documents directory to it.
I then use this array to populate a `UITableView` however... I constantly get the warning

> 'NSArray' may not respond to 'removeObjectAtIndex:'

If I change it to an `NSMutableArray` then that warning goes away but a new warning pops up here:

```
self.files = [[[manager contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:documentsDirectoryPath
                                            error:nil]
                          pathsMatchingExtensions:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"html", nil]] retain];
```

That warning is:

> Incompatible pointer types assigning to 'NSMutableArray *' from 'NSArray *'

The app works fine, as editing the table view never produces any problem despite the `removeObjectAtIndex:` issue.

Comment: Break up long statements into separate lines and it is a lot easier to spot the errors. You would have immediately seen that `[[manager contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:documentsDirectoryPath error:nil]` returned an `NSArray` and not an NSMutableArray. OPr gotten an error on that line pinpointing the error. There is no payoff to combining operations on one line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `mutableCopy` rather than `retain`:

```
self.files = [[[manager contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:documentsDirectoryPath error:nil]
               pathsMatchingExtensions:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"html", nil]]
               mutableCopy];
```

Comment: @Zaph: This has nothing to do with ARC (except that you would need to add an `autorelease` without ARC), it's about turning an `NSArray` into a `NSMutableArray`.

Comment: @Zaph: Then why did you mention ARC in the first place?

Answer (score 1):

`pathsMatchingExtensions` returns a plain NSArray object.

When I need a mutable array but get an immutable array, I will often use `[NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:anArray]`.

In your case, you might change your line of code to:

```
self.files = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[[manager contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:documentsDirectoryPath error:nil]
                                                        pathsMatchingExtensions:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"html", nil]]];
```

Comment: `[anArray mutableCopy]` is less typing ;-) Except if you're not using ARC, but I'd still prefer `[[anArray mutableCopy] autorelease]`... I think the intention is more clear but it's just a matter of taste.

Comment: @DarkDust You've got a point there :)  I'll just leave this answer as another option.

Comment: Thank you @Aaron.  I marked the other answer as correct, simply because it was posted first.  It wouldn't let me accept right away, so that is why nothing was accepted at the time you posted this.